# Repeating numbers in order in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, repeat

I'm a beginner in R so I hope this isn't something too obvious. I'm trying to create a vector which will repeat numbers, but it has a caveat which I can't make with `rep()`: the function must repeat the first number of a vector x for y times, and only then repeat the second number for y times, then the third etc. So for example, using `rep` I get:

```
 > rep(1:3, 5)
 [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

But I would like:

```
> 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

What I did manage to do was create a function which returns this specific vector (1:3):

```
some.func <- function(x,y){
for(i in x){
    if(i == 1){
        a <- rep(i,y)
    }else if(i == 2){
        b <- rep(i,y)
    }else if(i == 3){
        c <- rep(i,y)
        print(var <- c(a,b,c))
    }
    }
}
> some.func(1:3, 5)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

But that clearly works only if the vector does not go beyond 3. And now I'm stuck. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `rep(1:3, each=5)`

Comment: Well, it was pretty obvious....thank you.

Answer (score 0):

P Lapointe's answer:

```
rep(1:3, each=5)
```